# ServiceStack + Swagger - CredentialsAuthProvider

Tags: authentication, servicestack, restful-authentication, swagger-ui

How to authenticate ServiceStack with Swagger UI when custom authentication provider is implemented (CredentialsAuthProvider).

For basic authentication provider I would just send Authorization header with base64 encoded user:password but how about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of **v4.0.43+** that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet), ServiceStack's [Swagger API Feature](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Swagger-API) supports adding a `UserName` and `Password` which gets sent in [HTTP Basic Auth Headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) for each Swagger request allowing access to authenticated Services:

[image: Swagger UI Basic Auth]

This uses `BasicAuthProvider` is to enable authentication via [HTTP Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) which can be enabled when registering your `AuthFeature` with:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(...,
    new IAuthProvider[] {
        new BasicAuthProvider(appSettings), 
        ...
    });
```

If you only have `CredentialsAuthProvider` enabled, you'll need to first authenticate outside of Swagger, e.g. manually calling the URL:

```
/auth/credentials=Username=xxx&Password=xxx
```

If successful you can then access authenticated Services using the Swagger UI.

Comment: can you please give more details on this: "_...which Swagger doesn't let you do_"? Isn't this a workaround for basic auth:
`window.authorizations.add("key", new ApiKeyAuthorization("Authorization", "Basic "+key, "header"));` and to send a key as base64 encoded username:password ?

Comment: @ShP FYI as I thought this was a good feature to have, I've just added it to the latest v4.0.43+ that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: Great! Thanks so much.